# Android webview don't display AMP-story-timeline element

Tags: android, android-webview, amp-html, amp-story

I'm trying to display amp-story in webview, and it's working fine on ios/swift, but when i'm using android/kotlin, "amp-story-timeline" element is not render and just leaving empty space

[Kotlin/Black lines on top is where timeline should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBIIO.png)

[Swift/Timeline is showing ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43XaH.png)

My kotlin webview config:

```kotlin
WebView(it).apply {
            layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            )
            webViewClient = WebViewClient()
            webChromeClient = WebChromeClient()
            settings.cacheMode = WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT
            setCookiesEnabled(true)
            CookieManager.getInstance().acceptThirdPartyCookies(this)
            settings.domStorageEnabled = true
            settings.databaseEnabled = true
            settings.useWideViewPort = true
            settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
            settings.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture = false
            settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
            val extraHeaders: MutableMap<String, String> = HashMap()
            extraHeaders["Referer"] =
                Intent.URI_ANDROID_APP_SCHEME.toString() + "//" + context.packageName
            loadUrl(urlToRender, extraHeaders)
        }
```

Comment: Are you able to find out any solution for this?

Comment: @Ali_Waris unfortunately, no